# Can I configure Xamarin Forms application to retrieve data from Google Calendar API?

Tags: xamarin, google-api, xamarin.forms, google-calendar-api

wonder if someone has more experience and may give me a little help with this topic. My idea is to build cross platform app in Xamarin. Main request is to retrieve events data from user's google calendar. My quest. here is how to auth this request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events.

Should i register both ios/android project in Google API console or can i try with OAuth 2.0? Since i didn't find any example, is this possible with Xamarin forms?
Best Regards,
Ilija

Answer (score 4):

The Google Calendar API offers simple HTTP endpoints. You can access those through 100% cross plattform code with the help of `HttpClient` or [Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)

There is a Quickstart Guide for .NET at: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

As far as my knowledge goes: the Google API Console is useful to additionally limit the access (so nobody can take your credentials and use them in an App with a different android package name / iOS bundle identifier)

Comment: Have you used the .net client library with a Xamarin project?

Comment: I have not used that library. Technically there should not be a problem using it since it is implemented as a portable class library (which includes usage in Xamarin projects). If there are device specific issues i haven't found any.

Comment: Any ideas on how to go about authorisation? The referenced Google quickstart guide above gives code to set a user credential, but this doesn't work when debugging on an Android device (throws an exception - `"Failed to launch browser with \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&resp…"`)